# How can I call second largest number from arrayList using collections

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I need highest, second highest and third highest numbers from my `ArrayList`. I am getting max value (i.e. highest number) by calling `Collections.max()` but I also need the second largest and the third largest values.
My Code:

```html
maxPartyid = 
Collections.max(electionresdashlist.get(k).getPartyNamesDTO());  //1st Highest
                         
System.out.println( "maxPartyid:::"+maxPartyid);
             
in DTO :
public class PartyNamesDTO implements Comparable<PartyNamesDTO>{

    private String partyId;
    public String getPartyId() {
        return partyId;
    }
    public void setPartyId(String partyId) {
        this.partyId = partyId;
    }
    private Integer votes;
    
    
    public Integer getVotes() {
        return votes;
    }
    public void setVotes(Integer votes) {
        this.votes = votes;
    }
    
    @Override
        public int compareTo(PartyNamesDTO emp) {
            return this.votes.compareTo(emp.getVotes());
        }
    
        public String toString(){
            return partyId;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sort, then take first, second, thrid, fourth...

Comment: You already did 95% of the complex work here, and you couldn't find how to do the remaining 5%, which is to sort and get the n-th element.

Comment: Sir, Can you explain In detail!

Comment: have you looked at `heap`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use java 8 streams to sort and skip unnecessary elements

```
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(2).skip(1).findFirst()
```

`findFirst()` returns an `Optional<T>` of your object.

Comment: Same qyestion was asked to me in interview I did little differrently `list.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).skip(2).findFirst().get()`

Answer (score 7):

```
list.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).distinct().limit(2).skip(1).findFirst().get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you implemented the `Comparable` interface on `PartyNamesDTO` you can just do

```
Collections.sort(electionresdashlist)
```

which will make your list sorted according to `compareTo` logic and if your sorting is ascending order then you can get max record as

```
electionresdashlist.get(electionresdashlist.size()-1);
electionresdashlist.get(electionresdashlist.size()-2);
electionresdashlist.get(electionresdashlist.size()-3);
```

and if it is descending order the other way around

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer integer2 = numbers.stream().max((x,y)->x.compareTo(y)).get();
        
Integer integer3 = numbers.stream().filter(x->x<integer2).max((x,y)->x.compareTo(y)).get();
        
System.out.println("Second max is: "+integer3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get last -1
PartyNamesDTO tmpObj = partyList.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).skip(1).findFirst().get();

get first-1
PartyNamesDTO tmpObj = partyList.stream().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).skip(1).findFirst().get();
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution to find an *nth* highest element from the Array List:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(12,44,76,1,8,9,9));

int highest = arr.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(n-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
Collections.sort(electionresdashlist);

System.out.println( "maxPartyid:::"+electionresdashlist.get(0).getPartyNamesDTO());
System.out.println( "2nd maxPartyid:::"+electionresdashlist.get(1).getPartyNamesDTO());
System.out.println( "3rd maxPartyid:::"+electionresdashlist.get(2).getPartyNamesDTO());


in DTO :
public class PartyNamesDTO implements Comparable<PartyNamesDTO>{

    private String partyId;
    public String getPartyId() {
        return partyId;
    }
    public void setPartyId(String partyId) {
        this.partyId = partyId;
    }
    private Integer votes;


    public Integer getVotes() {
        return votes;
    }
    public void setVotes(Integer votes) {
        this.votes = votes;
    }

    @Override
        public int compareTo(PartyNamesDTO emp) {
            return this.votes.compareTo(emp.getVotes());
        }

        public String toString(){
            return partyId;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long largest=0, secondLargest=-1, thirdLargest=-2;
listName.forEach(item -> {
if(item > largest) {
    thirdLargest = secondLargest
    secondLargest = largest;
    largest = list.get(i);
  }
  if(item > secondLargest && item != largest) {
   thirdLargest = secondLargest; 
   secondLargest = item;
  }
  if(item>thirdLargest && item != secondLargest) {
   thirdLargest = item;
  }
});
```

Other approach is using comparator arrange the list elements based on no of votes and top 3 will give you your results

Answer (score 0):

```
static void getKthHighest(List<Integer> list, int k) {
    Optional<Integer> element = list.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).limit(k).skip(k - 1).findFirst();
    if(element.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(element.get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] arr= {80,19,32,150,2,78};
IntStream arrstream=Arrays.stream(arr);
OptionalInt firstmaxNum=stream.max();

IntStream secondmaxstream=Arrays.stream(arr);
OptionalInt secondMaximum=stream1.filter(s->s!=maxNum.getAsInt()).max();

System.out.println(" first maximum number :" +firstmaxNum.getAsInt());
System.out.println(" second maximum number :" +secondMaximum.getAsInt());}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the list is like below

List numbers = Arrays.asList(5, 9, 11, 2, 8, 21, 1, 21);

getKthHighest(numbers, 2);

```
static void getKthHighest(List list, int k) {
        Optional element = list.stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).distinct().limit(k).skip(k - 1).findFirst();
        if (element.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(element.get());
        }
    }
```

@Saheb provided a good answer but needs to Add distinct() for better results. if 2 no are duplicates then it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Search again the max without the first max, so you get the second max.